# Align items baseline for a select

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've got a header. In this header there's a title and a picker. The picker is a simple label with a select underneath it. I wish to align the baselines of the title and the text inside the select. If I use `align-items: baseline`, then the baseline of the title is aligned with the baseline of the label, not the text in the select.

How can I align the baseline of the title with the baseline of the select, instead of the label?

The reproducing code is

```
<div style="display:flex;align-items:baseline">
    <span style="font-size:23px;padding-top:16px">A title</span>
    <div>
        <div><span>A label</span></div>
        <div><select><option>An option</option></select></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this what you mean - http://jsfiddle.net/72k0g26b/

Answer (score 2):

> How can I align the baseline of the title with the baseline of the
>   select, instead of the label?

Based on your markup, what you need is `margin-top:auto` on your title `span`.

```
div.wrap > span { margin-top: auto; }
```

However, that may not really be an exact baseline because that would depend a lot on the `font-size`, `line-height`, `padding` etc. not only on your title `span` but also on the `select` itself.

The snippet below will help to visualize that with the red line showing the baselines:

**Snippet:**

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0; margin: 0; }
div.wrap { display: flex; margin: 8px; position: relative; }
div.wrap > span { margin-top: auto; margin-right: 4px; font-size: 1.5em; }
div.wrap select { padding: 2px; }
div.wrap::after {
    content: ''; display: block;
    position: absolute; left: -4px; bottom: 4px;
    width: 240px; height: 1px;
    background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrap'>
    <span>A title</span>
    <div>
        <div><span>A label</span></div>
        <div><select><option>An option</option></select></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Accompanying Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/n4z98wvn/**

---

Now why is `baseline` not aligning with the baseline? It actually does. If you split your label into multiple lines, you'll see that it does align with the baseline of the first line. You could see that clearly by comparing it with `flex-start`.

As pointed out by @Paulie_D, you could also get the intended result with `flex-end`. However the same problem as mentioned in my first solution, remains. You could see that clearly by comparing it with a reduced `line-height` on title.

Below are all the comparisons.

**Comparison Snippet:**

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0; margin: 0; }
div.wrap { display: flex; align-items: baseline; margin: 16px; }
div.wrap > span { font-size: 23px; border: 1px solid #ddd; }

div.wrap:nth-of-type(2) { align-items: flex-start; }
div.wrap:nth-of-type(3) { align-items: flex-end; }
div.wrap:nth-of-type(4) { align-items: flex-end; }
div.wrap:nth-of-type(4) > span { line-height: 20px; }
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <span>A title</span>
    <div>
        <div>
            <span>
                A label<br/>which breaks into<br/>lines, 
                is aligned at baseline with the title.
            </span>
        </div>
        <div><select><option>An option</option></select></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
    <span>A title</span>
    <div>
        <div>
            <span>
                A label<br/>which breaks into<br/>lines, 
                is aligned at flex-start with the title.
            </span>
        </div>
        <div><select><option>An option</option></select></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
    <span>A title</span>
    <div>
        <div>
            <span>
                A label<br/>which breaks into<br/>lines. 
                The select is mis-aligned with the title.
            </span>
        </div>
        <div><select><option>An option</option></select></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
    <span>A title</span>
    <div>
        <div>
            <span>
                A label<br/>which breaks into<br/>lines. 
                The select is aligned neatly with the title.
            </span>
        </div>
        <div><select><option>An option</option></select></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Comparison Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/r8spzk54/1/**

Comment: Holy cow, `margin-top: auto` solved my problem where I wanted to baseline-align some `align-items: stretch` children and `align-self: baseline` was being ignored! But for the sake of robustness, what would be the exact scenarios under which that solution wouldn't work, and how could I reproduce them? Thanks in the meantime!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

HTML (no changes; except removed some inline styles and added `id`)

CSS

```
#container {
    display: flex;
}

#container > div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/c7n0222p/4